# how to use map value by key when the value is an address C++

Tags: c++

I use map to get the address of globals in another file
and my function is extern "C"

```
const map< const char*, void*> GlobalVars = {
            { "A", &A },
            { "B", &B },
            { "C", &C },
            { "D", &D }
        };


        extern "C" void GetAddrByName(const char * str)
        {
            auto it2 = GlobalVars.at(str);//this return garbedge
             return;

        }
```

I don't understand why I don't get the address properly and get junk and when I put this line `auto it = GlobalVars.at("A");` everything works fine.

Comment: What are `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`?

Comment: And what is that empty `return` statement? You should change the function to return `void*`, and then return that `it2`. The compiler probably sees that you're not doing anything with this variable so it optimizes it out, which means you see "garbage" on the debugger. This is just one guess of out of several possible options of course. It's kinda hard to say given the information that you provide here.

Comment: So make up your mind - "you get junk" or "everything works fine"???

Comment: Just use std::string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because key you pass to `GlobalVars.at("A")` is address to a location that differs from what you passed during map initialization. In fact problem is not about pointer value.

For example, for `const char *a1 = "A";` and `const char *a2 = "A";` in your code, then `a1` is not equal to `a2` because they point to different memory locations (depending on compiler). So, `char *` cannot be used as map key here! Use std::string as key.

Comment: Possibly, though since they are both `const char*`, a good compiler (or linker) might actually create a single string (located in the RO section of the executable image) which both will point to (hence both will attain the same value). But I guess that this is not necessarily guaranteed by the language standard.

Comment: @goodvibration but it does not work if for example key is provided by user at stdin

Comment: That would never be a `const char*` (though you could then force-cast it as one, but it means that'd be doing something quite wrong in a very explicit manner).

Comment: `const char *` means that the called function won't change it. Absolutely you can cast user's input to `const char *`

Comment: Ali, he/she will need to take that `char*` (used for obtaining user input), and **explicitly** cast it to `const char*` before passing it to the function. So while this is possible, it is highly unlikely that he/she are actually doing that in the parts of code not provided in the question. Without the casting, they would get a compilation error.

Comment: But cast from `A` to `const A` is done implicitly and is used a lot.

Comment: @goodvibration No, the conversion is [implicit](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cac6bb6bc2225118).

Comment: @goodvibration You can pass a `char*` to `void GetAddrByName(const char * str)` perfectly fine just like passing a `char*` to something like `strlen()`. A `const char*` parameter type doesn't mean "string literals only".

Comment: @goodvibration any type. for example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: Anyhow, the point of using `string` as key is probably correct, since the comparison will surely be on the contents of that `string`, rather than on an address, such as in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The map will not work as you expect because it will compare pointer values instead of string content. So unless the input key is actually pointing to the exact `const char*` that you used during initialization of the map, it will not find the key.

If you want to use `const char*` as key for your map in this situation (and not switch to use `std::string`), you will need to provide a comparator to the map so that it performs actual string comparison.

For example:

```
struct cmp_str {
    bool operator()(const char* a, const char* b) const {
        return strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    }
};

const map< const char*, void*, cmp_str> GlobalVars = {
            { "A", &A },
            { "B", &B },
            { "C", &C },
            { "D", &D }
        };
```

Keep in mind that this map can potentially be dangerous because the comparator is dereferencing the pointers. So you need to make sure that no dangling pointer ends up as key, or you will get UB. But in the way that you are using it (with string literals as keys and as a const map) it should be safe.